# Is it changed Dispatching functionality in Phalcon PHP?

Tags: php, controller, phalcon, dispatcher, dispatch

I read something in Phalcon documentation about **Dispatching** ([view here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events)). I was used before "afterExecuteRoute", but just check documentation today about it... and i found something that bothers me (about parameters):

```
public function afterExecuteRoute(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
{
    // Executed before every found action
}
```

This is exact part of code from documentation. But if i placed that in my code, i will get "**Catchable fatal error**" about:

> Argument 1 passed to Adapters\Controllers::afterExecuteRoute() must be
>   an instance of Phalcon\Events\Event, instance of
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher given

So... is documentation wrong? Or this will be the right way in next Phalcon version?

Thanks

Comment: `beforeExecuteRoute` != `afterExecuteRoute`

Comment: What php version you are using and phalcon version ?

Comment: Phalcon version is 2.1.0r :) Thanks!

Comment: And what php version ? 7 or 5.6 ? If it's 7 make sure you compiled it using latest zephir and you have latest phalcon 2.1.0r

Oh i mean i just saw that you have ```Adapters\Controllers::afterExecuteRoute()``` Then in this case there is never ```$event``` passed to any of those methods. ```$event``` object is only if you are using events manager. Just only dispatcher object :)

Comment: no no, i am not with 7... currently is PHP Version 5.6.3 (win 32). Anyway, i think $event it is not placed right in documentation... in link i provide for dispatcher, the example is in/for controller.

Comment: Everything is right. You just added method to controller. `$event` occurs ONLY IN events manager obviously. In controller with method `afterExecuteRoute` there is no event fired, only `$dispatcher` passed to this method. Just remove `$event` argument :)

Comment: Yes, they answer to me in phalcon git hub. They will fix the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There indeed seems to be an inconsistency in the documentation.

Taken from the [controller docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#events-in-controllers), this example shows that the first parameter of 
`beforeExecuteRoute` needs to be a `Dispatcher` object.

```
class PostsController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function beforeExecuteRoute($dispatcher)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's done in controller then yes - only $dispatcher is passed beacause there is no event. If there is events manager used then you will have always event as first argument and object you are passing to fire method.